openapi-generator not adding @JsonCreator import statement for enums mentioned in openapi specification
I am using the following openapi-generator (version 7.2.0 i.e., latest version) command to generate java-undertow-server code
openapi-generator generate -i openapi.yaml  -g java-undertow-server -o undertow-server --additional-properties=openApiNullable=false,disallowAdditionalPropertiesIfNotPresent=false

The code generated doesn't have @JsonCreator import statements that is annotated for the enums types that are created based on the openapi.yaml specification. How can I resolve this issue? I want to generate the code on the fly and want my code to use the generated code, so I cannot add the import statements manually.
I had thoughts of customizing the openapi template but dont want the overhead of having to maintain the custom template.
